# How to create dynamic columns (same number of columns in header & row) using XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have an XML data source:

```
<ws:Report_Data xmlns:ws="urn:com.ws.report/Expense_Data">
    <ws:Report_Entry>
        <ws:uID>
            <ws:id>1</ws:id>
        </ws:uID>
        <ws:Journal_Entry_Group> 
            <ws:Ledger_Accounts ws:Descriptor="Q1: TEST1">
                <ws:ID ws:type="Ledger_Account_ID" ws:parent_type="Account_Set_ID"
                    ws:parent_id="Standard">Q1</ws:ID>
            </ws:Ledger_Accounts>
        </ws:Journal_Entry_Group>
        <ws:line>
            <ws:Number>000123</ws:Number>
        </ws:line>
        <ws:line>
            <ws:Number>000124</ws:Number>
        </ws:line>
    </ws:Report_Entry>
    <ws:Report_Entry>           
            <ws:uID>
                <ws:id>2</ws:id>
            </ws:uID> 
        <ws:Journal_Entry_Group>
           <ws:Ledger_Accounts ws:Descriptor="Q1: TEST1">
                <ws:ID ws:type="Ledger_Account_ID" ws:parent_type="Account_Set_ID"
                    ws:parent_id="Standard">Q1</ws:ID>
            </ws:Ledger_Accounts>
            <ws:Ledger_Accounts ws:Descriptor="Q2: TEST2">
                <ws:ID ws:type="Ledger_Account_ID" ws:parent_type="Account_Set_ID"
                    ws:parent_id="Standard">Q2</ws:ID>
            </ws:Ledger_Accounts>
        </ws:Journal_Entry_Group>
        <ws:line>
            <ws:Number>000596</ws:Number> </ws:line>
    </ws:Report_Entry>
</ws:Report_Data>
```

Based on the number of ws:ledger_accounts returned, I want to create the columns of the ledger account id and the description. The column header is generated dynamically as well (adding number _1, _2 and so on in the Ledger_Account_ID and Ledger_Account_Descheader name).

Based on the sample data source above, the second report entry has the highest number of ws:Journal_Entry_Group/ws:Ledger_Accounts returned, and so my header column should have 2 and the data row should have exact number of columns as well. The delimiter is <|> while the data row is enclosed with "".

Example expected Output:

```
uID<|>Ledger_Account_ID_1<|>Ledger_Account_ID_2<|>Ledger_Account_Desc_1<|>Ledger_Account_Desc_2|Number
"1"<|>"Q1"<|>""<|>"Q1: TEST1"<|>""<|>"000123"
"1"<|>"Q1"<|>""<|>"Q1: TEST1"<|>""<|>"000124"
"2"<|>"Q1"<|>"Q2"<|>"Q1: TEST1"<|>"Q2: TEST2"<|>"000596"
```

The XSLT code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="xsl" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:ws="urn:com.ws.report/Expense_Data">
    
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#xA;'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="delimiter"><![CDATA["<|>"]]></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="delimiter1"><![CDATA[<|>]]></xsl:variable>
    
    <xsl:template match="/ws:Report_Data">
        
        <xsl:text>uID</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter1"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="ws:Report_Entry[count(.//ws:Ledger_Accounts) = max(../ws:Report_Entry/count(.//ws:Ledger_Accounts))]//ws:Ledger_Accounts/concat('Ledger_Account_ID',$delimiter1)" separator=""/>                   
        
        <xsl:value-of select="ws:Report_Entry[count(.//ws:Ledger_Accounts) = max(../ws:Report_Entry/count(.//ws:Ledger_Accounts))]//ws:Ledger_Accounts/concat('Ledger_Account_Desc',$delimiter1)" separator=""/>        
        
        <xsl:text>Number</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/ws:Report_Data/ws:Report_Entry/ws:line"/>
    </xsl:template>
        
        
        <xsl:template match="/ws:Report_Data/ws:Report_Entry/ws:line ">
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="../ws:uID/ws:id"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            <!-- Ledger_Account_IDs -->            
            <xsl:if test="count(../ws:Journal_Entry_Group/ws:Ledger_Accounts) > 1">
                <xsl:for-each select="../ws:Journal_Entry_Group/ws:Ledger_Accounts">                
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(ws:ID[@ws:type='Ledger_Account_ID'])"/>
                    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each> 
            </xsl:if>   
            <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            <!-- Ledger_Account_Desc -->
            <xsl:if test="count(../ws:Journal_Entry_Group/ws:Ledger_Accounts) > 1">
                <xsl:for-each select="../ws:Journal_Entry_Group/ws:Ledger_Accounts">                            
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(@ws:Descriptor)"/>
                    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each> 
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="ws:Number"/>            
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>  
            <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
        </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the output is incorrect, the data row is not sync up with the number of columns in the header. For the first two lines it only creates 1 ledger account id column, should have at least another ""<|> before it goes to Ledger_Account_Desc column and the header can’t make it incremental.

Incorrect Output:

```
uID<|>Ledger_Account_ID<|>Ledger_Account_ID<|>Ledger_Account_Desc<|>Ledger_Account_Desc|Number
"1”<|>"Q1"<|>"Q1: TEST1"<|>"000123"
"1”<|>"Q1"<|>"Q1: TEST1"<|>"000124"
"2"<|>"Q1"<|>"Q2"<|>"Q1: TEST1"<|>"Q2: TEST2"<|>"000596"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `separator` attribute of `value-of` and then use a function to wrap each value in quotes; XSLT 3 would be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="urn:com.ws.report/Expense_Data"
    xmlns:ws="urn:com.ws.report/Expense_Data"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="delimiter" as="xs:string"><![CDATA[<|>]]></xsl:param>
  
  <xsl:param name="linefeed" as="xs:string" select="'&#10;'"/>
  
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  
  <xsl:function name="mf:quote" as="xs:string">
      <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
      <xsl:sequence select="'&quot;' || $input || '&quot;'"/>
  </xsl:function>
  
  <xsl:variable name="max-accounts" select="max(//Report_Entry/count(.//Ledger_Accounts))"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of
        select="'uID', 
                (1 to $max-accounts)!('Ledger_Account_ID_' || .), 
                (1 to $max-accounts)!('Ledger_Account_Desc_1' || .),
                'Number'" 
        separator="{$delimiter}"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//line"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="line">
      <xsl:value-of
        select="(../uID/id, 
                for $i in 1 to $max-accounts return string(../descendant::Ledger_Accounts[$i]/ID), 
                for $i in 1 to $max-accounts return string(../descendant::Ledger_Accounts[$i]/@ws:Descriptor),
                Number) ! mf:quote(.)" 
        separator="{$delimiter}"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>      
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNvtBGj